# Can Elasticsearch do a decay search on the log of a value?

Tags: elasticsearch

I store a number, `views`, in Elasticsearch.  I want to find documents "closest" to it on a logarithmic scale, so that 10k and 1MM are the same distance (and get scored the same) from 100k views.  Is that possible?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#exp-decay describes [field value factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) and [decay functions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay) but can they be "stacked"?  Is there another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can achieve this directly with decay, but you could easily do it with the `script_score` function. The example below uses dynamic scripting, but please be aware that using [file-based scripts](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting) is the recommended, far more secure approach.

In the query below, the `offset` parameter is set to 100,000, and documents with that value for their 'views' field will score the highest. Score decays logarithmically as the value of views departs from `offset`. Per your example, documents with 1,000,000 and/or 10,000 have identical scores (0.30279312 in this formula).

You can invert the order of these results by changing the beginning of the script to multiply by `_score` instead of divide.

```
$ curl -XPOST localhost:9200/somestuff/_search -d '{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "function_score": {
            "functions": [
              {
                "script_score": {
                  "params": {
                    "offset": 100000
                  },
                  "script": "_score / (1 + ((log(offset) - log(doc['views'].value)).abs()))"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Note: you may want to account for the possibility of 'views' being null, depending on your data.